# How to install OpenStack/Eucalyptus on AWS using EC2 instances

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, openstack, amazon-ec2

I would like to build a private cloud platform on AWS using either Openstack or Eucalyptus, but don't have a lot of experience in neither.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 0):

Try Juju: [Configuring for Amazon Web Services](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-aws.html#configuring-for-amazon-web-services)